# Filtering out only true values from Pandas DataFrame, return tuples of (Row,Col)

Tags: python, pandas

Given a frame like this:

```
  a    b     c
1 True False False
2 True True False
3 False True True
```

I want to get a list like this:

```
[(1,a), (2,a), (2,b), (3,b), (3,c)]
```

That is filtering out all the values that are true and retrieving tuples (rowName, colName)

Comment: Ok. What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach is to use `stack`:

```
>>> s = df.stack()
>>> s[s].index.tolist()
[(0L, 'a'), (1L, 'a'), (1L, 'b'), (2L, 'b'), (2L, 'c')]
```

which works because `stack` here returns the flattened version:

```
>>> df.stack()
0  a     True
   b    False
   c    False
1  a     True
   b     True
   c    False
2  a    False
   b     True
   c     True
dtype: object
```

Comment: Always looks so simple :)

Comment: You can even do this in one line `df[df].stack().index.tolist()`. `df[df]` is much slower than `s[s]` though.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
       a      b      c
1   True  False  False
2   True   True  False
3  False   True   True

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

You can find the indices corresponding to `True`s using `np.where`:

```
In [28]: np.where(df)
Out[28]: (array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]))

In [29]: x, y = np.where(df)
```

The index and columns are ndarrays, you can select the labels using NumPy integer indexing:

```
In [30]: df.index[y]
Out[30]: Int64Index([1, 1, 2, 2, 3], dtype='int64')

In [31]: df.columns[x]
Out[31]: Index([u'a', u'b', u'b', u'c', u'c'], dtype='object')
```

and put it together with `zip`:

```
In [32]: zip(df.index[y], df.columns[x])
Out[32]: [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c')]
```